# Python - 'str' object has no attribute 'close'

Tags: python, file-io

I am having a great time trying to figure out why there doesn't need to be a closing attribute for this few lines of code I wrote:

```
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists

script, from_file, to_file = argv

file_content = open(from_file).read()
new_file = open(to_file, 'w').write(file_content)

new_file.close()

file_content.close()
```

I read some things and other people's posts about this, but their scripts were a lot more complicated than what I'm currently learning, so I couldn't figure out why.

I am doing Learning Python the Hard Way and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`file_content` is a string variable, which contains contents of the file -- it has no relation to the file. The file descriptor you open with `open(from_file)` will be closed automatically: file sessions are closed after the file-objects exit the scope (in this case, immediately after `.read()`).

Comment: Aha! Thank you very much. I didn't realize the distinction between strings and objects in this form.

Answer (score 3):

`open(...)` returns a reference to a file object, calling `read` on that reads the file returning a string object, calling `write` writes to it returning `None`, neither of which have a `close` attribute.

```
>>> help(open)
Help on built-in function open in module __builtin__:

open(...)
    open(name[, mode[, buffering]]) -> file object

    Open a file using the file() type, returns a file object.  This is the
    preferred way to open a file.

>>> a = open('a', 'w')
>>> help(a.read)
read(...)
    read([size]) -> read at most size bytes, returned as a string.

    If the size argument is negative or omitted, read until EOF is reached.
    Notice that when in non-blocking mode, less data than what was requested
    may be returned, even if no size parameter was given.
>>> help(a.write)
Help on built-in function write:

write(...)
    write(str) -> None.  Write string str to file.

    Note that due to buffering, flush() or close() may be needed before
    the file on disk reflects the data written.
```

Theres a couple ways of remedying this:

```
>>> file = open(from_file)
>>> content = file.read()
>>> file.close()
```

or with python >= 2.5

```
>>> with open(from_file) as f:
...     content = f.read()
```

The `with` will make sure the file is closed.

Comment: You better not overwrite variable `file`. So it's better to say `with open(from_file) as f: ...` instead of `with open(from_file) as file: ...`.

Comment: Thank you. I need to get into the habit of reading Python docs. Because I get overwhelmed and lost, I try to avoid it, but I need to start getting used to it.

Comment: @Re-l no problem `help` is awesome, I wish more languages would have built in, instead of having to dig through tons of links before you get to what you are looking for ... it all does is grab the comments for the underlying object you can even use it for documenting your own functions later own ...

Answer (score 1):

When you do `file_content = open(from_file).read()`, you set `file_content` to the contents of the file (as read by `read`).  You can't close this string.  You need to save the file object separately from its contents, something like:

```
theFile = open(from_file)
file_content = theFile.read()
# do whatever you need to do
theFile.close()
```

You have a similar problem with `new_file`.  You should separate the `open(to_file)` call from the `write`.

Comment: Thank you for clearing this up. Your example helped me understand it. I did not think about the difference between a string and the file object.

Comment: The difference is not the case here. `theFile` is a file, while `theFile.read()` is a string which does not have a close function.

Comment: @Nasir I'm trying to see if I understand this correctly: so the reason why I didn't need a close function is because 'file_content' is a string (because I called 'read' on it)?

Comment: @Re-l: The reason you "don't need" to close is that Python will automatically close the file if there are no more references to it.  When you do `open('file').read()`, you throw away the reference to the file itself and only keep the contents, so Python will see that there are no references to the file and close it.  However, this might not happen right away.  It's safer to explicitly close the file once you're done reading the data.

Comment: @BrenBarn Ahhh! It just clicked. THANK YOU, good sir, for explaining it like that. I see what's happening now. :D